# Audited-activerecord gem not working properly for polymorphic associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, audit

I want to make audits for nested associations like I have

User has_many addresses i.e either

HomeAddress or OfficeAddress

Now if I have just one table Address and I have used type and id for differentiating them.In this case if I use associated_audits for User then it will make just one audit record and whenever I update the record again ,its just replacing the previous audit with the last one.

Here is the models association:

```
class Patient <  ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable,
         :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable, request_keys: [:subdomain]

  has_one :home_address,-> { where(addr_type: 'home') },class_name: 'Address'
  has_one :office_address,-> { where(addr_type: 'office') }, class_name: 'Address'
  has_associated_audits

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :home_address, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :office_address,  allow_destroy: true
end


class Address < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :patient
  audited

end
```

Comment: "In this case if I use associated_audits for User then it will make just one audit record" Audit or Address? If you want help please post your models and schema, don't just assume people will know what you're talking about

Comment: I have mentioned the details.Now you can update patient with nested attributes for either home address or office address and can check there would be only one audit for it everytime you update patient

Comment: If you're still getting the bug from above you might want to try changing your `type` column. It's a reserved name in rails and often causes bugs

Comment: Yes I know it, that's why I have used `addr_type` .But I think that's not the cause.I think the problem could be the association audits implemented for `has_one`  for audits.

Comment: #Rocco did you ever implemented this in your any application ? Or just passing suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

```ruby
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :patient
  audited associated_with: :patient
end

class Patient <  ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :addresses
  has_associated_audits
end
```

Comment: But It will also group other model audits if we have more than two associated audits

Comment: Actually,I don't want to use `has_many :addresses`.Patient has one office address and one home address only . Also ,It will break at running migration when we use audited for any specific column .